# Which Loft Insulation Type is best for the top floor of a three story house?

Tags: insulation

I have a three story detached house which uses a lot of energy, particularly in the winter. I'm looking to insulate the loft but I'm not sure which kind of insulation to go with. Glass wool seems like option, but a friend says she has some rigid foam insulation going spare, which is probably enough to cover my attic. What would be the best option to go with, or should I use another sort of insulation material?

Comment: Where are you located (region, height) and what is the climate over the year (temperature, humidity) - [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Blown or batts. See [HomeDepot for a comparison](http://www.homedepot.com/p/compare/?errorURL=ProductAttributeErrorView&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&prodComp_0=100541755&prodComp_1=100318635&N). Look at R-Value and height and depth. Also, both fiberglass and cellulose can iritate your lungs. So wear a respirator. Also check out [the HomeDepot recommended R value for your zone](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Owens-Corning-AttiCat-Fiberglass-Expanding-Blown-in-Insulation-System-L38A/100541755). I would suggest cellulose. BTW, I DO NOT suggest buying from Home Depot or any other big box. Keep your purchases local if you can.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to address the question - which is best and why. Just giving a couple of examples with links to a shopping site doesn't really help the person asking the question (especially if they're not in the USA). That site also claims Sydney, Australia isn't a place...